# enum operators not working

Tags: c++, enums, operators

My app has lots of bitfield enums that need various supporting functions (toString(), fromString(), countSetBits(), isValid(), etc…). So I used the CRTP to make a base class with static functions for everything I need.  Everything works great, EXCEPT, I can’t get the bitwise operators to work.  So...

Why don’t operators 1 and 2 allow A and B to compile?

Operators 3 and 4 work, and they look the same to me.  (Actually, the implementation of 4 doesn't compile and I could use some help with that too..)  (C-style casts only used to save space)

Stumped.  Please help!

```
#include <type_traits>

using EnumUnderlying_t = unsigned;

template <typename EnumWrapper_t> struct EnumBitfieldBase {
    //CRTP allows for lots of handy static functions eliminating code duplication.  For example:
    static void test(){
        if constexpr (!std::is_same<EnumUnderlying_t, typename std::underlying_type<typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum>::type>::value){
        throw;
    }
}
//also: toString(), fromString(), countSetBits(), isValid(), largestValidValue(), allBitsSet() etc...
};

//operator #1
template <typename EnumWrapper_t>
inline constexpr typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum operator|(const typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum L, const typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum R) {
    return (typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum)((EnumUnderlying_t)L | (EnumUnderlying_t)R);
}

//operator #2
template <typename EnumWrapper_t>
inline constexpr typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum & operator|=(typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum & l, const typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum R) {
    return (typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum &)((EnumUnderlying_t &)l |= (EnumUnderlying_t)R);
}

struct Option : public EnumBitfieldBase<Option> {
    enum Enum : EnumUnderlying_t {
        None = 0,
        Lame = 1 << 0,
        Boring = 1 << 1,
        Stupid = 1 << 2
    };
};

/*
//operator #3
inline constexpr Option::Enum operator|(const Option::Enum L, const Option::Enum R) {
    return (Option::Enum)((EnumUnderlying_t)L | (EnumUnderlying_t)R);
}

//operator #4
inline constexpr Option::Enum & operator|=(Option::Enum & l, const Option::Enum R) {
        return (Option::Enum &)((EnumUnderlying_t &)l | (EnumUnderlying_t)R);
}
*/

int main(void) {
    Option::test();
    Option::Enum options{ Option::Lame | Option::Boring };//A -works only with c++17...why?
    options = (Option::Stupid | Option::Boring);//B -only works with operator #3
    options |= Option::Lame;//C -only works with operator #4
    if (options & Option::Lame) { /*do something lame*/ }
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:  Okay, I figured out that operators 1 and 2 will not work because of "non-deduced context".  Basically, template deduction won't work for something to the left of ::...So what is the right way to base class (or otherwise solve the problem of) enums used as bitfields?  I don't want to use the namespace trick because I need the type to participate in template deduction.  Anyone?

Comment: Have you considered an enum `class`?  Maybe the class would allow you to place methods into it, instead of using templates.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you.  Adding the 'class' keyword to the enum declaration does not make it an actual class that can have member functions, and even if it did, then I would have to add those member functions to all my enums, which is what I'm trying to avoid with the base class.  Could you put your suggestion another way please?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- `enum class` is not a class. It reuses `class` to mark it as different from a plain `enum`. It's still an `enum`, but the enumerations are scoped within the name of the `enum` rather than going into the containing scope, as they would with a plain `enum`.

Comment: I tried it and still get an error saying there is no operator taking two Option::Enum.  It's as if my function signature is wrong somehow...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare them as `const` methods; otherwise they will only be allowed to work on lvalues, and your constants are not lvalues (they are const, obvioulsy).

```
//operator #1
template <typename EnumWrapper_t>
inline constexpr typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum operator|(const typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum L, const typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum R) const {
    return (typename EnumWrapper_t::Enum)((EnumUnderlying_t)L | (EnumUnderlying_t)R);
```

(Change is in the last word in the third line)

Comment: Adding const produces the error: "non-member function cannot have 'const' qualifier"  These operators are not member functions.  I don't think they can be member functions because the type being operated on is EnumWrapper_t::Enum.

Comment: Oh, I see. I remember now that I ran into a similar issue a while ago. Haven't found a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I've found to make operators 1 and 2 work.  Please post if you know a better way!

```
//operator #1
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
inline constexpr T operator|(const T L, const T R)
{
    return static_cast<T>(static_cast<EnumUnderlying_t>(L) | static_cast<EnumUnderlying_t>(R));
}

//operator #2
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
inline constexpr T & operator|=(T & l, const T R)
{
    l = static_cast<T>(static_cast<EnumUnderlying_t>(l) | static_cast<EnumUnderlying_t>(R));
    return l;
}
```